# Error de compilación using que no encuentro

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Uso VS 2017 me sale el error:
Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CapadelProyecto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Error de código fuente:


Línea 26:     using System.Web.Routing;
Línea 27:     using ProyectoPortafolio;
Línea 28:     using CapadelProyecto;
Línea 29:     using Helper;
Línea 30:     using Modelo;


Archivo de origen: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\891665ff\1ed88e6a\App_Web_index.cshtml.44e9485f.ndbnfirz.0.cs    Línea: 28
```

Pero no puedo encontrar el using CapadelProyecto por ninguna parte y el error dice que está en App_Web_index y tampoco encuentro eso.

Comment: Te pasa en ambos debug y release?

Comment: realiza la prueba de detener el iis express, cerrar el VS, volver abrir la solucion y realizar un rebuild, si puedes ademas elimina todo el contenido de la carpeta "Temporary ASP.NET Files"

Comment: No encuentro la carpeta, ¿En dónde debería estar?